# Why is a button firing the event of a previous element/tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure what's causing the form button to fire the event of turning the page theme back to white after the dark mode has been clicked and enabled.
Not sure if that may be confusing, but for example if you open the page it's automatically on the light mode theme, when you click "dark" to switch the theme to dark and then click the button "search" while the theme is in "dark", the page will switch back to "light". What am I doing wrong or missing out? Please advise. Also, how could I refractor this JS better and simpler?

Thanks!

**HTML** - left out the head part intentionally

```
<html lang="en" color-mode="light">

  <body>
    <header class="header-container">
      <h1 class="title">devfinder</h1>
      <div class="light-dark mode">
        <span
          class="theme-toggle-btn light-hidden light"
          aria-label="light theme toggle button">
          LIGHT
          <img class="light-icon" src="assets/icon-sun.svg" alt="" />
        </span>

        <span
          class="theme-toggle-btn dark-hidden"
          aria-label="dark theme toggle button">
          DARK
          <img src="assets/icon-moon.svg" alt="" />
        </span>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main class="content-container">
      <section>
        <form autocomplete="off" class="form" id="search">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="search"
            placeholder="Search GitHub username…" />
          <button class="btn">Search</button>
        </form>
```

**JS**

```
const themeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".theme-toggle-btn");

const toggle = function (e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains("light-hidden")) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("color-mode", "light");
    localStorage.setItem("color-mode", "light");
    return;
  }
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("color-mode", "dark");
  localStorage.setItem("color-mode", "dark");
};

themeBtn.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", toggle);
});
```

**CSS**

```
:root {
  --monoFont: 'Space Mono', monospace;
  --accent-blue: #0079FF;
  --error-red: #F74646;
  --light-hover: #60ABFF;
}

:root[color-mode="light"] {
  --primary-text-color:#697C9A;
  --secondary-text-color: #4B6A9B;
  --accent-color: #2B3442;
  --background-color: #F6F8FF;
  --container-background: #FEFEFE;
  --font-color: #222731;
}

:root[color-mode="dark"] {
  --primary-text-color: #FFFFFF;
  --background-color: #141D2F;
  --container-background: #1E2A47; 
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root[color-mode="light"] .light-hidden,
:root[color-mode="dark"] .dark-hidden {
  display: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-color: var(--background-color);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  color: var(--primary-text-color);
  font-family: var(--monoFont);
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.header-container, .content-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 730px;
}

/* header title */
.title {
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-size: 1.63rem;
}

/* theme toggle btn */
.theme-toggle-btn {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  border: none;
  
  color: var(--primary-text-color);
  font-size: .7rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;

  cursor: pointer;
}

.theme-toggle-btn img {
  margin: 0 0 -0.45em 0.75em;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

/* search form */
.form {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 69px;
}

.form input {
  background-color: var(--container-background);
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;

  color: var(--font-color);
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;

  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 12px;;

}

.form input::placeholder {
  color: var(--secondary-text-color);
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-80%);

  width: 100%;
  max-width: 106px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: var(--accent-blue);
  border: none;

  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1rem;

  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--light-hover);
}
```

Comment: An easy fix is to add `type="button"` on the `<button>` within the search form. Better would be to add an event handler for the forms `submit` event, where presumably you want to use the search query.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you're clicking the "Search" button, it's refreshing the page and reloads the html template. Because you have "color-mode="light" within the html element, it will then load the page in light mode rather than dark mode.

Comment: How can I stop the button from refreshing the page? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is: your not consuming the selection from localStorage. To persist the user selection, you should check the preference in localStorage when the page loads.